# Can I set possible types of a type argument?

Tags: typescript

Let's see I want to build a function:

```
type A = {
  foo: boolean
};
type B = {
  bar: boolean
}

type PossibleObjects = A | B

type Object <T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: boolean
}

const fn = <
T //:PossibleObjects
>(object: Object<T>) => object;
```

Even though this function doesn't make anything useful, it's good to explain what I want. I want to control what `T` can be, in this case `A` or `B`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by narrowing the generic type `T` to extend your possible Objects.

```
type A = { foo: boolean };
type B = { bar: boolean };
type PossibleObjects = A | B

type SomeObject <T> = {  // Renamed to "SomeObject" since "Object" is already a default type
  [key in keyof T]?: boolean
}

const fn = <T extends PossibleObjects> // This makes T a subtype of PossibleObjects
   (object: SomeObject<T>) => object;

fn({ foo: true });  // Works
fn({ bar: true });  // Works
fn({ baz: true });  // Error: Argument of type '{ baz: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SomeObject<A> | SomeObject<B>'.
```

If your `SomeObject` type can only ever (and not just in your `fn` function) specify keys that are in your `PossibleObjects` type, you might want to do this on your `SomeObject` type as well.

```
type A = {
  foo: boolean
};
type B = {
  bar: boolean
}

type PossibleObjects = A | B

type SomeObject <T extends PossibleObjects> = { // Adds the type constraint here
  [key in keyof T]?: boolean
}

// Now the following works
const fn = <T extends PossibleObjects>(object: SomeObject<T>) => object;
// But this one will NOT be valid anymore 
const fn2 = <T>(object: SomeObject<T>) => object; 
// Error:                          ^
// Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'PossibleObjects'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pipe (|) operator to provide different types:

```
function fn(arg: A | B): any {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `extends` sets an upper bound on a type argument. This works both on type declarations and on function declarations.

```js
type SomeObject<T extends PossibleObjects> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: boolean
}

const fn = <T extends PossibleObjects>(obj: SomeObject<T>) => obj;
```

Note that `T` here isn't constrained to be either `A` or `B`; `T` could also be `PossibleObjects` itself. I don't think there is a way to prohibit that, but you should be aware of it.